# Dynamically load templates (partials) in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load a template into an Angular app depending on a parameter. It would be inside a ng-foreach:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ExampleController as example">
   <div  ng-repeat="item in example.items" class="someClass" ng-switch="item.type">
      <!-- load a different template (partial) depending on the value of item.type -->
   </div>
</body>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/rsvmar2n/1/

Can I somehow do that? I was thinking about using ng-switch: https://jsfiddle.net/rsvmar2n/6/

But I'm sure there's a more angular way to do it.

Edit: I would like NOT to do an http request for every partial I would load (and I think ngInclude does that.

Edit2: Ended using **ng-include** and *cached templates*. https://jsfiddle.net/rsvmar2n/24/

Comment: What about `ngInclude`?

Comment: Yes. I thought of that but it's not clear to my how it works (Angular documentation's magic). Should i expose from my server some HTML's and then load them with ngInclude? Can you bring a code example? I would like NOT to do an http request for every partial I would load (and I think ngInclude does that).

Comment: you can use `ng-include` over `$templatecache`

Comment: [check](https://jsfiddle.net/rsvmar2n/14/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a function which returns the id of the template in ng-include and use cached templates. The working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ktq2ocp0/2) shows what you can do.

the function in your controller which handles the template looks like:

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(item) {
    switch(item.type)
  {
    case "type1":
        return 'testtype1.html';
    default:
        return 'testtype2.html';
  }
}
```

and your html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="testtype1.html">
  <p>This is the template 1</p>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="testtype2.html">
  <p>This is the template 2</p>
</script>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="someClass">
    <!-- load a different template (partial) depending on the value of item.type -->
    <div ng-include="getTemplate(item)"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: note that ng-include has security flaws and should be avoided

Comment: @PenchoIlchev nevermind, the answer is 5 years old ;)

Answer (score 3):

Create directive for that, something like:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {item: '=item'},
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs){
      if (!attrs.type) return 'default.html';
      return attrs.type + '.html';
    }
  } 
});
```

Then you can create different templates like type1.html, type2.html...

And in controller you just do:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in items" item="item", type="item.type">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ng-include lets you dynamically assign the source - so in your parent template you could have

```
<div ng-include src="templateName"></div>
```

where templateName is a variable name in your controller

```
$scope.templateName = 'path/to/my/template.html';
```

and changing this value within a digest should dynamically update the contents for you

Answer (score 0):

Based on conditions you can load single or multiple templates as shown below.

With **ng-switch**

```
ng-if="item.type=='type2'||item.type=='type3'"
```

[LoadMultipleTemplate](https://jsfiddle.net/rsvmar2n/19/) To load multiple template based on your selections.

[LoadSingleTemplate](https://jsfiddle.net/rsvmar2n/14/) load single template.

**Edit**

With **ng-include**, this way you can load dynamic views.

in this example I've not put any condition. but within ng-repeat you can put another ng-repeat and based on inner ng-repeat you can do the stuff. But for inner ng-repeat you will have to make according json object.

[loadViews](https://plnkr.co/edit/ILmsBg8oQtIUHdqrCSux?p=preview)

```
<div  ng-repeat="item in example.items" class="someClass" >

         <ng-include src="item.type + '.html'">{{item.type}}</ng-include>

</div>
```